# Empty output while trying to convert a yaml data into a struct

Tags: go, struct, yaml

Im trying to convert a yaml data into a struct and print it. The output I get for this program is empty.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"

"gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type example struct {
    variable1 string
    variable2 string
}

func main() {
    var a example
    yaml.Unmarshal([]byte("variable1: asd\nvariable2: sdcs"), &a)
    fmt.Println(a.variable1)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Unmarshal) for `Unmarshal` states that

> Struct fields are only unmarshalled if they are exported (have an upper case first letter) and are unmarshalled using the field name lowercased as the default key.

So capitalizing your struct elements is the right thing to do.

```
type example struct {
    Variable1 string
    Variable2 string
}
```